# How can I toggle the value of an svg text element with D3.js when user clicks the text?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have just started to learn D3.js and have written a small program to test some ideas that I plan to implement in a larger program. Referring to the code here, the initial value of the text is 0. I am trying to have the value toggle between 1 and 0 when a user clicks on the text. There is something wrong with what I’ve coded in .on(“click”…) because the text does not change to 1.  What am I doing wrong?

I've found examples of updating .attr, but I can't find anything about toggling .text in the manner I want.

```
            var txt1 = g.append("text")
                        .attr("id", "txt1")
                        .text("0")
                        .attr("x", 10)
                        .attr("y", 17)
                        .attr("font-family", "Arial")
                        .attr("font-size", "12")
                        .attr("fill", "black")   
                        .on("click", function(){
                            if (d3.select(this).text === "0"){
                                d3.select(this).text("1")
                            }
                            else{
                                d3.select(this).text("0");
                            }
                        } )
```

When I click on the text element the first time I expect to see it change to "1".

Comment: to get value you have to call `.text()`, not just `.text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text content of the SVG element directly you can use `textContent` or `innerHTML` in modern browsers. For instance:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var txt1 = svg.append("text")
  .text("0")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .on("click", function() {
    console.log(this.textContent)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

However, because you're using a **D3 selection**, not an SVG node, you should use `text` as a getter, which is `text()`. By the way, [`text()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/e2b3d37b911f1eb0974678b2134204e8c98e4c04/src/selection/text.js#L18) internally uses `textContent`:

```
export default function(value) {
  return arguments.length
      ? this.each(value == null
          ? textRemove : (typeof value === "function"
          ? textFunction
          : textConstant)(value))
      : this.node().textContent;
}
```

Finally, you don't need that `if` block. To toggle between `0` and `1`, just do:

```
this.textContent = 1 - (+this.textContent);
```

You can even drop the unary plus, since the string will be converted to a number anyway:

```
this.textContent = 1 - this.textContent;
```

Here is the snippet:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var txt1 = svg.append("text")
  .text("0")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .on("click", function() {
    this.textContent = 1 - (+this.textContent);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```